# Getting JRE version if Java is not installed in Safari using deployjava.js

Tags: java, javascript, safari, deployjava

I am using deployjava.js to check whether java or JRE installed in system or not. I create a script to check JRE version and java installed in system or not. I tested it in Safari browser in my Mac, but It shows me that **JRE version detected : 1.5+** while I don't have installed JAVA in my system.

Code to detect JRE version using depoyjava.js :

```
  var JRE_version = deployJava.getJREs();
```

How it this possible? Is it Safari browser issue or deployJava.js issue ?

Comment: Can you try to run any Java Applet in Safari and see if it is getting started or not? In this way you can confirm that Safari is using JRE or not.

Comment: try hitting this [link][(http://javatester.org/version.html) from safari. What does it shows.

Comment: I have tested this link for check JRE version but it shows 1.6+ version installed. @ankur-singhal

Comment: @GhanshyamKatriya so this means your broswer has JRE installed. )

Answer (score 0):

This is Javascript code, it works almost in all broswers.

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
     var versions = deployJava.getJREs();
     alert(versions);
</script>
```

Check this [link](http://javatester.org/version.html) to test the broswer version.

i have tested and viewed the source code, `java.tester.org`, they also user `deployJava.js`

In your case [this](https://www.chrisnewland.com/java-applet-deployment-using-deployjavajs-322) might help you.